# How can I do "su -c 'cmd' user" from Linux in macOS?

Tags: sudo

On Linux I execute:

```
su -c "ls -l /etc | mail -s filelist myname@gmail.com" - username
```

How does this work in macOS?

Answer (score 1):

```
su - <username> -c "ls -l /etc | mail -s filelist myname@gmail.com"
```

Comment: There's no `-c` option on macOS su, also the username shouldn't have `-` as a prefix. So The command will be: `su username command`

Comment: yes. But it work (a bug?) Try it!

Comment: It doesn't work with `-` in front of the username. Indeed `-c` works, but it is probably because of `-c` option for `bash`. So if you pass the arguments as a string you have to provide `-c` option. But for `su` you can skip `-c` and pass the args without the quotes

Comment: sorry a write mistake